# Using mutable sequence types as default attribute values together with @property in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, properties, attributes

I get stuck on the following. I am trying to initialize some class attributes with default values, where the default values are mutable sequence types (list and numpy array). Because I want to have some error checking every time an attribute is set from outside the class I'm using the @property feature.

```
import numpy as np
from FDTimeBase import FDTimeBase
from FDString import FDString

class FDObjNetwork(FDTimeBase):

    def __init__(self,i_mechObjs=[FDString(),FDString(101)],i_connPointMatrix=np.array([[0.5],[0.5]]),\
                 i_excPointMatrix=np.array([[0.5],[0.]])):
        self._mechObjs = i_mechObjs
        self._connPointMatrix = i_connPointMatrix
        self._excPointMatrix = i_excPointMatrix

    @property
    def mechObjs(self):
        """the mechanically vibrating objects making up the network"""
        return self._mechObjs

    @property
    def connPointMatrix(self):
        """
        the connection point matrix of the network, where each row
        denotes a separate element in the network and each column
        denotes a separate connection
        """
        return self._connPointMatrix

    @property
    def excPointMatrix(self):
        """
        the excitation point matrix, where each row denotes a
        separate element in the network and each column denotes a
        separate excitation distribution
        """
        return self._excPointMatrix

    @mechObjs.setter
    def mechObjs(self,newMechObjs):
        try:
            [obj.k for obj in newMechObjs]
        except AttributeError:
            raise AttributeError('argument mechObjs contains an invalid object')
        else:
            self._mechObjs = newMechObjs.tolist()[:]

    @connPointMatrix.setter
    def connPointMatrix(self,newConnPointMatrix):
        try:
            newConnPointMatrix[:,0]
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('argument connPointMatrix must be a 2D indexable object')
        else:
             self._connPointMatrix = np.asarray(newConnPointMatrix).copy()

    @excPointMatrix.setter
    def excPointMatrix(self,newExcPointMatrix):
        try:
            newExcPointMatrix[:,0]
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('argument excPointMatrix must be a 2D indexable object')
        else:
            self._excPointMatrix = np.asarray(newExcPointMatrix).cop()

    # public methods
    def calcModes(self):
        self.__checkDimensions()

    # private methods
    def __checkDimensions(self):
        if len(self.connPointMatrix[0,:]) != len(self.excPointMatrix[0,:]):
            raise Exception('arguments connPointMatrix and excPointMatrix must contain an equal nr. of rows')
        if len(self.connPointMatrix[0,:]) != len(self.mechObjs):
            raise Exception('the nr. of rows of argument connPointMatrix must be equal to the nr. of\
                            elements in mechObjs')
        if len(self.excPointMatrix[0,:]) != len(self.mechObjs):
            raise Exception('the nr. of rows of argument excPointMatrix must be equal to the nr. of\
                            elements in mechObjs')
```

Now when I create a new instance and try to access the mechObjs attribute I get an AttributeError and I don't understand why (same for the other two attributes). calling dir() on the instance I can see there are _mechObjs, _connPointMatrix and _excPointMatrix attributes which contain the list and array objects. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? The object FDString is another custom class, which I omitted posting, since the source file is rather large. FDTimeBase is an object just holding 2 constant class attributes (nothing fancy).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't create a new instance of this class because of the error in the `__init__` method (you are using `attr1` and `attr2` when the arguments to your function are `i_attr1` and `i_attr2`). When this is fixed, it works fine. Please post code that actually illustrates the problem you are having.

Comment: sorry, that's just a typo. But my original query remains. I can post all my original code, but its basically just the above.

Comment: Well, that code works fine, so post something that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your code works fine for me too.

Comment: I should have tried the above before posting, since it works for me too... However, my original code still doesn't for some reason. I'll edit my original query and replace it with all my original code then.

Comment: I don't know if this is your intention, but `attr1` and `attr2` are mutable, so they can be modified, for example, by doing `myobject=MyObject(); del myobject.attr1[:]`.  This bypasses any error-checking code in the setters, and you might run into the famous [mutable default argument problem](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/).

Comment: Well... I decided to paste all the original code into a new file and for some reason it all works fine now. The only reason I can think of is that I renamed the original file and class name. Maybe Aquamacs got confused by that somehow, although can't really see why this would have resulted in those errors. Anyway, problem solved I guess.